# Using rsyslogd on only 1 of 2 systems

Tags: rsyslog, netcat

I have two systems.  One is a laptop and has rsyslog. The other is embedded system that doesn't have rsyslog.  What I'd like to do is log messages from the embedded system on the laptop.

I've configured the laptop `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to listen on TCP port 10514:

```
netstat -nlp | grep 10514
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10514               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      30280/rsyslogd      
tcp        0      0 :::10514                    :::*                        LISTEN      30280/rsyslogd
```

On the embedded system I'm sending, a test message with netcat:

```
[172.17.0.33: ]# echo "Test Message 1" | nc -w2 -p 10514 172.17.0.16
nc: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.16): Connection refused
```

Is rsyslog expecting anything special in the packet? Does it require both systems to have rsyslog? Any other reason I'd get "Connection refused"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your `nc` command specify the destination port rather than the source port (-p). It seems you need to execute the command as below:

```
echo "Test Message 1" | nc -w2  172.17.0.16 10514
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot!  Thanks so much Daniel t.!!!

Answer (score 2):

Did you open inbound TCP port 10514 in the rsyslog server's firewall? You have to do that if you want to receive incoming connections.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Yes, I believe the firewall is completely disabled:      
    chkconfig --list | grep iptables      
    iptables        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off

Comment: chkconfig means it won't start on boot. It does not mean it's not running (although it wont be unless you accidentally started it, or disabled it after booting when it was actually enabled on boot).

Comment: Yes, I've rebooted since then, but just as precaution I did  /etc/init.d/iptables stop and am still getting "Connection refused".